# in laravel form value not storing in database and no error showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**i am passing form value but it not storing in database.**
**my model**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Center extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'centers';
    protected $fillable = ['center_code','center_name','center_head','contact_no','email','center_area_in_sft','number_of_systems','remarks','center_in_side_photo','center_out_side_photo','center_head_photo'];


}
```

**my route**

```
Route::post('franchise', 'MainpageController@franchise_registration')->name('franchise');
```

**my controller**
 public function franchise_registration(Request $request)

```
     { 

      $this->validate($request, [


          'center_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'center_head' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'contact_no' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'center_area_in_sft' => 'required|string|max:12',
          'number_of_systems' => 'required|string|max:10',
          'remarks' => 'required|string|max:255',

          'center_in_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
           'center_out_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
           'center_head_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',

         ]);
```

$input['center_head_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->center_head_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder1 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/');
        $path1 = $folder1 . $input['center_head_photo']; // path 1
        $request->center_head_photo->move($folder1, $input['center_head_photo']); // image saved in first folder
        $path2 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/') . $input['center_head_photo']; // path 2
        \File::copy($path1, $path2);

```
         $input['center_in_side_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->center_in_side_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['center_in_side_photo']; // path 1
    $request->center_in_side_photo->move($folder1, $input['center_in_side_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/') . $input['center_in_side_photo']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);

         $input['center_out_side_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->center_out_side_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['center_out_side_photo']; // path 1
    $request->center_out_side_photo->move($folder1, $input['center_out_side_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/') . $input['center_out_side_photo']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);


       $input['center_code']  ="KA_SIIT/".time();
       $input['center_name'] = strtoupper ($request['center_name']);
       $input['center_head'] = strtoupper ($request['center_head']);
       $input['contact_no'] = $request->contact_no;
       $input['email'] = $request->email;   
       $input['center_area_in_sft'] =  strtoupper ( $request['center_area_in_sft']);
       $input['number_of_systems'] =  strtoupper ( $request['number_of_systems']);
       $input['remarks'] = strtoupper ($request['remarks']);



    Center::create($input);
```

return back()->with('success','YOUR REGISTRATION SUCCESSFULLY.');
    }

**my view**

```
 <section class="our-work-area section-padding-90-70" id="Courses">
     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="welcome-text">    

<div class=" row justify-content-center">
                <!-- Single Work Area -->
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="single-work-area mb-30">

                        <div class="single-feature-area mt-30">
                            <!-- Icon -->
                            <div class="about-icon">

                            </div> 
                           <b> <u><h5><a href="#">FRANCHISE RIGISTRATION</a></h5></u></b>
                                                       @if(\Session::has('success'))
                         <div class="alert alert-success">
                           <p> {{\Session::get('success')}}</p>

                         </div>



   @endif<hr>                
  <div class="tab-content">
<form method="POST"  autocomplete="off"   action="{{route('franchise')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                            @csrf  
                                        <div class="row">





<div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="center_name" class="control-label">CENTER NAME</label>
                              <input placeholder="CENTER NAME" type="text" class="form-control required" name="center_name" id="center_name">
                                                </div>
```

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contact_no" class="control-label">CONTACT NO</label>
       <input placeholder="CONTACT NO" type="text" class="form-control required" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" numbers="onlynumbers" required autofocus maxlength="10" minlength="10"   pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="email" class="control-label">MAIL ID </label>
                                <input placeholder="E-MAIL" type="mail" class="form-control required" name="email" id="email" required >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>    

                                        </div>



       <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">


                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="center_area_in_sft" class="control-label">CENTER AREA IN SFT</label>
                      <input placeholder="CENTER AREA IN SFT" type="text" class="form-control required" name="center_area_in_sft" id="center_area_in_sft" required >
                                                </div>
```

```
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="number_of_systems" class="control-label"> NUMBER OF SYSTEMS</label>
                              <input placeholder="NUMBER OF SYSTEMS" type="text" class="form-control required" name="number_of_systems" id="number_of_systems" required >
                                                </div>
```

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
                                                      <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="center_head_photo" class="control-label">CENTER HEAD PHOTO</label>
                               <input placeholder="CENTER HEAD PHOTO" type="file" class="form-control required" name="center_head_photo" id="center_head_photo">
                                                    </div>


                                            </div>
```

CENTER INSIDE PHOTO

```
                                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="center_out_side_photo" class="control-label">CENTER OUTSIDE PHOTO</label>
                 <input placeholder="CENTER OUTSIDE PHOTO" type="file" class="form-control required" name="center_out_side_photo" id="center_out_side_photo">
                                                </div>


                                        </div>

 </div>

                                        <button style="float: right;"type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
                                        <br>

                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your `<form>` tag? Can`t find in view.

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh updated check ones

Comment: So nothing is getting added in table?

Comment: what does the $this->validate method do? It seems you are passing input into validate method, but there is no check whether the data is actually valid. After an attempt to store the data with Center::create($input); you redirect to another page immediately. If there is any error it will not be displayed because of the back() redirect.

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh tried from 3 days its not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code.

```
  $validator  = $this->validate($request, [


  'center_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'center_head' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'contact_no' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
  'center_area_in_sft' => 'required|string|max:12',
  'number_of_systems' => 'required|string|max:10',
  'remarks' => 'required|string|max:255',

  'center_in_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
  'center_out_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
  'center_head_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',

 ]);

 if ($validator->fails()) {
  return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())->withErrors();
 }
```

and put this code in top of your form

```
@if ($errors->any())
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <div>{{$error}}</div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Edit :

Put this line in `use` section `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

```
$validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [

'center_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
'center_head' => 'required|string|max:255',
'contact_no' => 'required|string|max:255',
'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
'center_area_in_sft' => 'required|string|max:12',
'number_of_systems' => 'required|string|max:10',
'remarks' => 'required|string|max:255',

'center_in_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
'center_out_side_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
'center_head_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',

]);
```

Comment: `$this->validate()` doesn't return a validator

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with print input error like

```html
<input type="text" name="center_name">
@if($errors->has('center_name'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('center_name') }}</div>
@endif
```